# Matlab - how to plot monte carlo paths transforming into horizontal histogram in one chart

Tags: matlab, plot, data-visualization, montecarlo

I want to create a chart which would present all the paths resulting from a simulation and then at the point t=T to transform it into horizontal histogram presenting the frequency of the end results.

Is this possible to do in one chart in Matlab?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. I understand the paths-vs-t part. But where do you want to plot on the right hand side? Along an additional dimension, so the result is 3d? Please elaborate. Oh, do you mean to plot a horizontal histogram starting from t=T, and extending further to the right?

Comment: I don't think it would be trivial: you'd probably need two axes (possibly, but not necessarily, in two `subplot`s), with linked `y` axes. The first for the trajectories, the second for the `barh` plot that shows the histogram (which you will have computed by then separately). But since the axes limits might be different for the two axes, using `linkaxes`/`linkprop` might not be straightforward.

Comment: Yes, I mean the transition into a horizontal histogram at the point t=T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a really nice way to do this, but I managed to hack together something which looks similar to what you describe. See below my example with a Monte Carlo simulation of a random walk.

```
% Setup, create test data
col = [0 0.2 0.741] ; % colour
rng(0) ; % reset random number seed

n = 20 ; % number of bins
Te = 1000 ; % simulation length
T = 600 ; % length of trajectory to plot
X = cumsum(randn(Te,1)) ;
```

Ugly plot code:

```
% create histogram based on the end of the sample
[H,C] = hist(X(T+1:Te),n) ;

% new figure
fh = figure(999) ;
clf() ;

% trajectory for the first part of the sample
ax0 = subplot(1,2,1) ;
lh = plot(X(1:T),'Parent',ax0) ;
lh.Color = col ;

% histogram for the second part of the sample
ax1 = subplot(1,2,2) ;
bh = barh(ax1,C,H,1) ;
bh.EdgeColor = col ;
bh.FaceColor = col ;
ax1.XTickLabel = '' ;
ax1.YTickLabel = '' ;

% make both axes have the same YLim property and make sure we don't clip anything
YLim(2) = max(ax0.YLim(2),ax1.YLim(2)) ;
YLim(1) = min(ax0.YLim(1),ax1.YLim(1)) ;
ax1.YLim = YLim ;
linkaxes([ax1,ax0],'y') ;

% bump the axes together
ax0.Position = [0.13 0.11 0.440552147239264 0.815] ;
```

It's not pretty but it works. Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes something like that except there would be n paths on the left hand side of T and then the histogram on the right hand side would present the end of the path values

Comment: Oh okay. I didn't understand. I will adjust my answer.